# comparing continuous spaces

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

we say $c(\Omega)$ contains all continuous functions on $\Omega$.
Also, $c^1(\Omega)$ contains all functions that are continuous  on $\Omega$ up to first derivatives. Now my question is that what is the difference between $c(\Omega)$ and $c^0(\Omega)$?

Comment: None, they are the same, but the notation $C(\Omega)$ is "lighter".

Comment: Occasionally, something like $c_0$ is used for compactly supported functions ...